# quotients of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the meaning of this quotients of polynomial rings 
 R[x] mod x.x ? I want to find some ring ,s.t.x.x=0, x is a 
element of the ring. Is there the ring? Is it R[x] mod x.x  ? 
What is the meaning? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The ring $R[x]/(x^2)$ is the quotient ring of the polynomial ring $R[x]$ by its ideal generated by $x^2$. In this quotient ring, the class of $x$ is not zero but its square is zero.

In fact, you can write every element of $R[x]$ as $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_dx^d$ for some $a_0,\dots,a_d\in R$ (by definition of $R[x]$), and it is equivalent to $a_0+a_1x$. So you can see $R[x]/(x^2)$ isomorphic as a $R$-module to $\{a_0+a_1x\mid a_0,a_1\in R\}\simeq R^2$. The multiplication is then given by $$(a_0+a_1x)(b_0+b_1x)=a_0b_0+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)x.$$

Comment: What is meant by $\simeq R^{2}$? Isomorphic as $R$-modules or as rings? What is the isomorphism?

Comment: Only as $R$-modules (as it is written). The map sends $a_0+a_1x$ onto $(a_0,a_1)$. This is not a ring-homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

On underlying set $R\times R$ define addition $\left(r,s\right)+\left(r',s'\right)=\left(r+r',s+s'\right)$
and multiplication $\left(r,s\right)\left(r',s'\right)=\left(rr',rs'+r's\right)$.

This makes it a ring with unit $(1,0)$ and zero $(0,0)$, and we denote this ring as $S$.

Note that $\left(0,1\right)^{2}=\left(0,0\right)$ in $S$.

There is a surjective
ringhomomorphism $\phi:R\left[x\right]\rightarrow S$ determined by
$x\mapsto\left(0,1\right)$.

Its kernel is the principal ideal generated
by $x^{2}$ leading to: $$R\left[x\right]\text{ mod }x^{2}\simeq S$$